# Application as Service on Centos 7

Tags: shell-script, centos, systemd, sysvinit

Pretty new to Centos 7 and most of my earlier experiences were with Ubuntu. I have just set up an application on Centos 7 and I saw on their product website that to run the application as a Linux Service (Start at System Startup), this is the script that one needs to use.

```
#! /bin/sh
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_07"

startcmd='<PRODUCT_HOME>/bin/listener_mm.sh start > /dev/null &'
restartcmd='<PRODUCT_HOME>/bin/listener_mm.sh restart > /dev/null &'
stopcmd='<PRODUCT_HOME>/bin/listener_mm.sh stop > /dev/null &'

case "$1" in
start)
   echo "Starting the Listener Server ..."
   su -c "${startcmd}" user1
;;
restart)
   echo "Re-starting the Listener Server ..."
   su -c "${restartcmd}" user1
;;
stop)
   echo "Stopping the Listener Server ..."
   su -c "${stopcmd}" user1
;;
*)
   echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart}"
exit 1
esac
```

Haha hope esac is not specific to other distro  :?

So I created the script, substituted the correct values as per my enviroment, and added a Symbolic link to my script. I have couple of questions
1) The above script is perhaps for Ubuntu or another Linux Distro. So do I need to make any changes to the script?
2) How do I make this run as a service , for all users? I would want this to start at System Startup. Debian / Ubuntu has update-rc.d, and I guess i need to use chkconfig for this. Can I have any pointers on this? It happens to be a machine with few other things, so I am a little vary of experimenting and if anyone with experience on this could give me some pointers, it will be great.

I am doing some reading on systemd but any help will be really appreciated.

Thanks a ton.

Cheers,
M.M

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To run something on startup on CentOS 7, Fedora, and recent versions of Ubuntu, you need to create a [systemd unit](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html).  What you have in your question is a legacy init script and is no longer necessary.

A simple unit file might look like this:

```
[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/myservice

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Assuming that `/bin/myservice` runs in the foreground, the above is really all you need.  You would place this into `/etc/systemd/system/myservice.service` if you are just setting things up on your own system, or `/usr/lib/systemd/system/myservice.service` if you are building a package for distribution, and then:

1. To start the service immediately: `systemctl start myservice`
2. To mark the service for automatic start next time you boot: `systemctl enable myservice`

Tools like `chkconfig` and `update-rc.d` are legacy tools that are not necessary in environments running systemd.

Comment: Thanks a lot larsks. I definitely am not building a package for distribution. I just need to be able to do exactly the same task that the above script does - Start, Stop and restart. Probably your unit file example is precisely what I need. I guess it should do what the script in my OP does? I am a total newbie to Centos 7 scripting / systemd etc :) Thanks once again

Comment: @MenonM - This is absolutely correct, `systemd` is the way to go in CentOS 7, pretty much all major distros switched to systemd in their latest release.  Doing the `service` start, stop and restart; just calls `systemctl` behind the scenes on CentOS 7.

Comment: You will need to add an additional line to the service unit to have it run as `user1` instead of `root`.

Comment: Thanks a lot larsks and grochmal. I just tried to copy + modify some stuff from an existing unit file (for nginx) .... and couldn't get my system to boot now :-) Luckily that was a pure test Centos 7 haha. But ya let me go with Systemd and see how. Unfortunately I have zero experience in scripting on Linux, but on Windows - kinda darn good ",)

Comment: MenonM, I've given you pretty much everything you need in this answer, except for setting the user, which I can think you can figure out from reading documentation.  You don't need to go modifying anything more complicated.  Start simple!